# C# Error converting bytearray from database to image

Tags: c#

I have run into a problem with a C# project I'm working at. I get an object array containing all the selected items from a database row with the function:

```
public static object[] getResultSet (string statement)
        {
            object[] resultArray=null;
            OleDbConnection con = getConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(statement, con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    resultArray = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(resultArray);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(),"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return resultArray;
        }
```

and I have this object array in which I have stored all the results:

```
object[] obj = getResultSet("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID=1");
```

I certainly know that the object obj[2] is a BLOB in my database because the debugger shows over 3mil bytes for my object. But when I try to convert the bytes array from the object I get informed that I didn't handle an exception:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid."

Here's the function I'm using to convert the bytes array to an image:

```
public static Image imageFromByteArray(byte[] bytearray)
        {
            Image img;
            ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();
            img=(Image)imgCon.ConvertFrom(bytearray);
            return img;
        }
```

I tried to call

```
imageFromByteArray((byte[])obj[2]);
```

but it didn't work, even with another function that converts an object to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] objectToByteArray(object obj)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: What's the issue when using the second method, `objectToByteArray`

Comment: @Stefan the same issue

Comment: Looks like `ConvertFrom` takes `object` as a parameter, not a byte array?

Comment: `ImageConverter` is used to convert from one image to another.  You're loading a *byte array*, not an image *object*.  Load the array into a `MemoryStream`, then use `Image.FromStream` to load the image data.  Don't use a serializer.

Comment: @Stefan I have already tried convert from the object directly, but the same issue occured.

Comment: @Amy Tried that. The same issue happened

Comment: Then it either a) isn't an image, or b) the data is corrupted somehow, or c) your attempt was somehow flawed.  Please show your attempt at my proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Before, I had manually added the image to the database, this is why it behaved so strangely.
In order to be recognized by my program, all the images needed to be programatically added.